# Euler Phi of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I saw an AIME problem where you took $\phi(1000)$ and then divided by $2$. The problem is here:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/u244443h580665p4722095

$\phi(1000)$ gives you how many numbers are coprime to $1000$ that are less than  $1000$.

How do you know half of them are exactly less than $500$ and half are exactly over $500$?

Answer (score 4):

Because when $a$ is coprime to $1000$, $1000-a$ is also. So they come in pairs, one less than $500$ and the other more than $500$.

Comment: This might be obvious, but one would have to point out that $500$ isn't coprime to $1000$.

Comment: I didn't give *any* "why." That's just one tiny part of the "why."

Comment: If $a$ is coprime to $1000$ then how is $1000 - a$ also coprime to $1000$? I need $\gcd(1000, 1000 - a)$ right? How to show that is $1$?

Comment: If $d\mid 1000$ and $d\mid 1000-a$ then $d\mid 1000-(1000-a)=a$. @Lebes

Comment: How does that prove the initial claim though?

Comment: Which "initial claim?" You asked one question - why are half of them more than $500$ and half less than $500$. You can partition the set into pairs, one $<500$ and one $>500$.

Comment: No, no. I understand that. What I dont understand still from your proof (2 posts above) is if $a$ is coprime to $1000$, then how is $1000 - a$ also coprime to $1000$? I know it has to do with $\gcd(1000, 1000 - a)$ but I dont know how to show it is $=1$?

Answer (score 0):

A helpful fact about the Euler phi function (I don't know if this fact is available to you) is that if a prime $p$ divides $n$, then $\varphi(pn)=p\varphi(n)$.

Thus $\varphi(1000)=\varphi(2\cdot 500)=2\varphi(500)$, which immediately gives your result.

Comment: How does that show that exactly half of them are $>500?$

Comment: Yes, fair point.  You'd have to additionally observe that since $500$ and $1000$ have exactly the same prime factors (though not with the same exponents), a number is relatively prime to $1000$ iff it is relatively prime to $500$.